# How to implement subtracting dates in my SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

So here's my code:

```
    SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, to_char(HIREDATE, 'Month YYYY'), SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) FROM EMP;

    CASE
    WHEN DEPTNO = 10 THEN 'Accounting'
    WHEN DEPTNO = 20 THEN 'Research'
    WHEN DEPTNO = 30 THEN 'Sales'
    WHEN DEPTNO = 40 THEN 'Operations'
    END AS DEPT
    FROM EMP;
```

I can use the select extract function separately in another command window but I can't seem to get it to work here in this query.  The query was successful before I added the date subtraction part.  Sorry for the noob question I'm very new to SQL.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is becuase you are using `SELECT ` again, `SELECT EXTRACT(...` should be `EXTRACT(...`. Also `...FROM HIREDATE) FROM EMP` should be `...FROM HIREDATE) `. Or Else if you want sub query then just put brackets around the `(SELECT     EXTRACT....FROM EMP) As extractedYear, Case ....`
Also in future always follow [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/643104) for asking better formatted questions.

Comment: In this particular case what was wrong with the way I formatted my question?  I just joined the site, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you dont need extra select

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, to_char(HIREDATE, 'Month YYYY'),  
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),

        CASE
        WHEN DEPTNO = 10 THEN 'Accounting'
        WHEN DEPTNO = 20 THEN 'Research'
        WHEN DEPTNO = 30 THEN 'Sales'
        WHEN DEPTNO = 40 THEN 'Operations'
        else null
        END AS DEPT
        FROM EMP;
```